# A simple "number of bit strings", so I thought

Tags: combinatorics

How many bit strings of length 10 contain at least three 1s and at least three 0s?

Answer (score 15):

Let's think about just placing the 0's and let the 1's fill in the remaining spots. The cases we are interested in are how to get *exactly* 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 0's.

How many strings have exactly 3 0's? This is just the number of ways to choose 3 locations out of 10 available locations where order doesn't matter, which is $\binom{10}{3}$. Remember, we're only focusing on the 0's - the 1's just fill in the remaining spots.

The argument is the same for getting exactly 4, 5, 6, and 7 0's. To get the total, we just add them all up:

$$
\binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4} + \binom{10}{5} + \binom{10}{6} + \binom{10}{7}.
$$

Comment: Your answer totally makes sense. Now I know why I was undercounting in my attempt. It seems for the at-least type of questions, a good approach to solve them is to use a systematic method as exemplified by yours to ensure correctness. Rushing to solve by a shortcut, especially in a test, probably will result in an incorrect answer. Thank you a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the complementary problem: at most 2 0s or at most 2 1s. The counts for each case is $\binom{10}{2}+\binom{10}{1}+\binom{10}{0}=56$; the count for at least 3 0s and at least 3 1s is therefore $2^{10}-2\cdot 56=912$

Answer (score 2):

As we will have 10 places total so this problem will get reduced to 10 places consisting of 7 zeros and 3 ones ,6ones and 4 zeroes, 5 ones and 5 zeroes.  so
$(2\cdot\frac{10!}{7!\cdot 3!})$   (one for 7 zeroes and 3 ones and other case is 3 ones and 7 zeroes)+$2\cdot \frac{(10!}{6!\cdot4!})$  (one case 6 ones and 4 zeroes and other vice versa)+ $\frac{10!}{5!\cdot 5!}$
so Total answer is 912

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The number of $0$s is between (this) and (that); how many strings of length $n$ contain exactly $k$ zeroes?